# Undefined reference to 'strnlen' despite "string.h" include

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, arm, lpc

I am trying to use create a project for LPC1769 on LPCXpresso. I have a C file calling

```
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    //some stuff
    strnlen(SomeString, someInt);
}
```

to which I get an error:

```
Undefined reference to 'strnlen'
```

The weird part is that there is no problem with strcpy, strncpy or other common string functions.

I am building for a Cortex-M3 processor
Compiler used is: arm-none-eabi-gcc
In Eclipse, I have ticked the MCU linker option : No startup or default libs
I am running Eclipse on Ubuntu

While it may be easy enough to bypass this by just using strlen, I am actually facing a problem using a library which uses strnlen, and I don't want to mess with the library source.

Comment: I changed the compiler header library from Redlib to Newlib in the Project C/C++ build settings in eclipse. This takes care of the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `strnlen` function was (until fairly recently) a Linux-specific function (some documentation such as the GNU [libc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Length.html) still says that it is a "GNU extension").  The current [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strnlen) says it is part of POSIX.1-2008. Since you are cross-compiling, it is possible that the target machine's runtime library does not have this function.  A [forum posting](http://www.lpcware.com/content/forum/strnlen-not-supported) from 2011 said just that.

Answer (score 2):

I add the same problem and I found out that using `-std=gnu++11` compiler flag solves it.

Comment: But this causes the code to be compiled as C++, right?

Comment: Sure, I guess the problem only shows up with c++, `strnlen()` being a POSIX-2008 API.

Answer (score -1):

The following may work for you (since strnlen() is not a part of the runtime lib).

Define your own/local version of the `strnlen()`.

```
int strnlen(char *param, int maxlen)
{  
    // Perform appropriate string manipulation ... as needed.
    // Return what you need.
};
```

Comment: Why is using a 'strnlen' wrapper/user defined function frowned upon ... especially when he is stuck with a library, the source of which he doesn't want to modify, and with a platform, where the runtime library doesn't have strnlen defined ... ?

Comment: Thanks. In that case, he can simply have a second parameter 'maxlength' in his definition of strnlen() and perform the appropriate string manipulation within this function & return what he needs. My point being ... a user-defined wrapper could probably solve his problem.

Comment: By 'perform the appropriate string manipulation' in my earlier comment I was not implying usage of strlen() within the wrapper. What I meant was: 'write your own version of strnlen()' within this user defined wrapper ...

Answer (score -3):

You want this include instead:

```
#include <string.h>
```

The difference between `<>` and `""` is that `<>` searches for header files in your systems include folder. The `""` searches for header files in the current directory and in any other include folders specified by `-I directory`

Comment: I think #include "" and <> both search everywhere, and "" searches the current directory first and then the system header files, while <> follows the other order. (edit - that is incorrect)
See (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename) for better explainantion of the difference.

Further, making that change does not solve the problem